How to write scripts of subxt for evm transactions?
I want to use subxt for performing transactions on evm chain.
Do we have resources where we are doing evm transactions?

The closest we have is an example of Subxt connecting with a ndoe that uses Ethereum based signature/accountID20's here:
https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/f034ac486cb04667934a5399e564b8e877e96c5d/subxt/examples/tx_basic_frontier.rs
Beyond some initial setup to use the correct AccountId20 and Eth style signatures, the rest of the steps are the same (point Subxt macro at metadata, and then use generated code to build and submit transactions).
.

If I recall correctly, for submitting transactions on frontier the evm pallet "dispatchables" cannot be executed directly, and you must use the the ethereum API. I used https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3, but any ethereum API will do. See https://github.com/paritytech/smart-bench/blob/master/src/evm/xts.rs#L150
